# Facebook API - uids and email

Tags: api, facebook

I am trying to develop a application where

1. The user 'X' has logged into Facebook
2. app has a set of email addresses (possible friends of user 'X')
3. app gets the list of friends of user 'X' (uids)
4. Want to check if user with email address some@some.com is a valid facebook user by using email address and is user X's friend (basically a uid to email mapping)

Comment: Cool app!  Did you want us to do something?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, this is possible.  First, get the UIDs for all of a user's friends.  Then, execute this FQL to get the email_hashes for each friend:

```
SELECT email_hashes FROM user WHERE uid IN (comma_delimted_set_of_uids)
```

Since you already have the email address, you can hash it and compare it to facebook's email_hash.  If you have a match, you know it's valid.  According to the FB documentation, the format of each email hash is the crc32 and md5 hashes of the email address combined with an underscore (_).

Answer (score -2):

First you need to get permisssion using oAuth dialog using FB api, in the example they have shown how they have populated the user name.