# Getting Facebook email/email hash

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, facebook

I'll make it short: is it possible to get the user's facebook email adress (or a hashed email adress), so I can let's say compare his facebook email with his email in my database? I'm trying to get a FacebookUser and then use facebookUser.email_hash but that returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

a similar question has been [asked here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959927/facebook-api-question-uids-and-email)

and, I [don't think fb api](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Talk:Users.getInfo#how_can_I_get_emailAddress_of_a_user) currently gives away the user email addresses.

Comment: It does, don't really know how but my teammate already did it.