# Get Email Hashes of My Facebook Connections

Tags: api, facebook

Is it possible? Just need the CRC32_MD5 hash they use, but can't seem to find the way of doing it.

Note that this is not a dup of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630039/getting-facebook-email-email-hash) since the question and it's answers are focused on getting the plain email, not the hash.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) to get this. Specifically the `email_hashes` field. You can then combine it with [connect.registerUsers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/connect.registerUsers/) and compare it with your existing user DB.