# Is it possible to get email hashes from UID with facebook api and HOW?

Tags: php, facebook, api, email

I already got the UID and I wanna get email hashes from UID. I also can fetch FQL to get user's name and sex etc but when I SELECT email_hashes it returns empty array. Any help?

Comment: Where does the FB documentation say that this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Facebook's [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/):

> An array containing a set of confirmed email hashes for the user. Emails are registered via the connect.registerUsers API call and are only confirmed when the user adds your application. The format of each email hash is the crc32 and md5 hashes of the email address combined with an underscore (_).

You don't get this for free just by getting an install - you only get them when you pass them in yourself via the `connect.registerUsers` API. If you want to e-mail a user, you'll need to get the `email` [permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/).

Comment: Thanks. But I am not wanna send email. I want to get the email hashes from facebook and compare them with my site's account email hashes. As the result I can find out my site's user who are also a facebook user. I think that's what www.quora.com have done in their sign up procedure. They also ask me to authority but only the access my basic information and they can get my friends uid, so I think they may get my friends' email hashes from uid. That's why I am asking.

Comment: That's still a privacy violation that Facebook is trying to avoid - users need to manually give you permission to associate their Facebook accounts with your site's accounts using e-mail addresses. I would ask your users for the `email` permission and then compare their actual e-mail to the e-mail in your database. Or, better yet, ask your users to associate their accounts with their Facebook accounts and simply associate with their Facebook user ID.

Comment: I have seen someone said it is possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959927/facebook-api-question-uids-and-email/2397798#2397798. And I am wondering how quora.com did this. If you choose connect your facebook account with your quora account quora will show you your facebook friends who also are quora users.

Comment: They do it in a different way, using your Facebook friends list and comparing that to their known Facebook user IDs. It has nothing to do with e-mail hashes.